# Freeradius check specific software version before accepting

Tags: networking, freeradius

is it somehow possible that the freeradius checks the database of the antivirus programm before accepting the client?

My system is running with a mix of MAC-addresses and certificates, but it should be advanced to trust the clients only if they have up-to-date databases on certain programms.

My first thoughts were maybe to do a systemcall and run a script to get the information even before checking for mac and/or certificates, but i honestly have no idea if this is possible.

I am also open for completely new systems (dont need to stick to radius), the most important thing is to check the database + certificates etc no matter what software  / server does this.

thanks in advance